# How to mount a second hard drive? Debian

Tags: debian, hard-drive, mount

hey, well I mounted my hard drive to var/www/disk2/

but obviously since the first hard drive is on /   all the files on var/www/disk2/ are going to count towards the space on the the first hard drive no? Cause that's what happened when I uploaded a file then checked disk space.

Thats the way it seems, how do i make it so the files in car/www/disk2 go to the second hard drive? I mounted it and everything to there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the files on /var/www/disk2 wont count towards the space on first drive.

Comment: really? alright ill try again

Answer (score 1):

Everything that is written to the filesystem under a mount point is stored to whatever drive is mounted there, not the drive that contains the mountpoint.

For example /dev/sda1 is mounted at /, and /dev/sdb1 is mounted at /home:
Writing a file to /home/user/file will only use space on /dev/sdb1, it has no effect whatsoever on the filesystem contained on /dev/sda1. The only thing that is on /dev/sda1 is the /home directory entry.

If by some chance, /dev/sdb1 was not mounted, then whatever is written to /home would then be on the filesystem contained on /dev/sda1.

Issue the mount command without any arguments to get a list of what is mounted and where.